# How to find the final value from repeated measures in R?

Tags: r

I have data arranged like this in R:

```
indv    time    mass
1         10    7
2          5    3
1          5    1
2          4    4
2         14    14
1         15    15
```

where `indv` is individual in a population.  I want to add columns for initial mass (`mass_i`) and final mass (`mass_f`).  I learned yesterday that I can add a column for initial mass using `ddply` in plyr:

```
sorted <- ddply(test, .(indv, time), sort)
sorted2 <- ddply(sorted, .(indv), transform, mass_i = mass[1])
```

which gives a table like:

```
   indv mass time mass_i
1    1    1    5      1
2    1    7   10      1
3    1   10   15      1
4    2    4    4      4
5    2    3    5      4
6    2    8   14      4
7    2    9   20      4
```

However, this same method will not work for finding the final mass (`mass_f`), as I have a different number of observations for each individual.  Can anyone suggest a method for finding the final mass, when the number of observations may vary?

Comment: Also, if anyone can tell me how to format tables on stackoverflow, I would really appreciate it!  I've seen it done, but can't seem to find any code when I click "edit" those posts.  Thanks!

Comment: Format as code by pressing the {} button above the edit window, or by manually indenting every row with at least 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `length(mass)` as the index of the last element:

```
sorted2 <- ddply(sorted, .(indv), transform,
                 mass_i = mass[1], mass_f = mass[length(mass)])
```

As suggested by mb3041023 and discussed in the comments below, you can achieve similar results without sorting your data frame:

```
ddply(test, .(indv), transform,
      mass_i = mass[which.min(time)], mass_f = mass[which.max(time)])
```

Except for the order of rows, this is the same as `sorted2`.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for your help.  I know this is a silly question, but I'm obviously completely new at R.  I really appreciate the help though.  :)

Comment: This works, but more general code --that doesn't assume the observations are sorted by time-- would find the max time for each person and use that to index the mass:

df <- ddply(df, .(indv), transform, mass_f=mass[which.max(time)])

Comment: @mb3041023, that is true. But when you already know that the list is sorted, there is no point in repeating that work. If you were working on unsorted data, then `which.max` in combination with `which.min` would be appropriate,

Comment: Absolutely true.  I just want to make this issue explicit for readers who can easily read the question's title and ending text but may struggle with the caveats implied by the ddply code in the middle.  And since your answer is great, I'm (clumsily) trying to get you to expand on the point. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tail(mass, 1)` in place of `mass[1]`.

```
sorted2 <- ddply(sorted, .(indv), transform, mass_i = head(mass, 1), mass_f=tail(mass, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have this table, it's pretty simple:

```
t <- tapply(test$mass, test$ind, max)
```

This will give you an array with `ind.` as the `names` and `mass_f` as the values.

Comment: Seems like you made the same mistake as I originally did in reading the question: it's not the maximum `mass` value which should be found, but instead the value associated with the maximum `time`, i.e. the *last* value.

Comment: Got it. Then probably `test$mass[which(test$time==(tapply(test$time, test$ind, max)))]`